# Datetime format and dataframe and dictionary combine

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format

I have two questions , i will be gradeful if you can help me please

- I want to have the date format of dataframe's column format as DD/ MM /YYYY

`df_main['DT EWS'] = pd.to_datetime(df_main['DT EWS'],format= "%d/%b/%Y" )` doesn't work , I have the same result as `2019-03-19`

How can I get `19-03-2019` without any `00:00:00`   (19.03.2019  00:00:00) only day - month - year please

2. I want to combine dictionary and dataframe

```
names = {203:"AYDOGANLAR"}  - CODE  : NAMES
```

df_main has some columns mentioned below , I want to combine df and dictionary names which have CODE AND NAMES

```
df_main.dtypes
DATA TYPE                 object
CODE                      int64
dtype: object
```

[image: code]

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook for Python

Comment: You just parse to datetime dtype; you'll also need to convert back to string in the desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert date column in required format you can use below code:

```
df_main['DT EWS']=df_main['DT EWS'].astype('datetime64')
df_main['DT EWS'].dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

If you can elaborate more on second query, I can help you on this.